# How can i push php code to js variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I want push this php code to javascript variable like a string,
is it posible?

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("wt:static.content", "bonus10", array(
        "DEFAULT_LANG" => array(
        0 => "",
),
    "LANGUAGE_ID" => "",
    "USE_DEFAULT" => "Y",
    "INCLUDE_LANGUAGE" => "",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "3600"
),
false,
array(
    "ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y",
    "HIDE_ICONS" => "N"
)
);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: It might help if you explain why you want to do this. Generally, PHP should be kept on the server, so this is a little out of the ordinary. If you need to use part of this code on the client, you could output HTML with a JS script tag and echo the PHP variable there.

Comment: im doing it via nodejs, for automatic template creator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var string = '$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("wt:static.content", "bonus10", 
                                            array("DEFAULT_LANG" => array(0 => "",),
                                            "LANGUAGE_ID" => "",
                                            "USE_DEFAULT" => "Y",
                                            "INCLUDE_LANGUAGE" => "",
                                            "CACHE_TYPE" => "Y",
                                            "CACHE_TIME" => "3600"),
                                            false,array("ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y",
                                                            "HIDE_ICONS" => "N"));
                                                            require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php"‌​);?>';
```

Comment: thank you very much all most done, but when it writing this string to file i saw this result:
`$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("wt:static.content", "bonus10", array(NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN`
is it posible to fix?

Comment: `var string = '$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("wt:static.content", "bonus10", array('
    +' "DEFAULT_LANG" => array( '
    + '0 => "",'+
    +'),'+
    +' "LANGUAGE_ID" => "", '
    + ' "USE_DEFAULT" => "Y", '
    + ' "INCLUDE_LANGUAGE" => "", '
    + '"CACHE_TYPE" => "Y", '
    +'"CACHE_TIME" => "3600"'
    +'),'
    +'false,'
    +' array('
    +'"ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y",'
    +' "HIDE_ICONS" => "N"'
    +')'
    +');'
    +' require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>';`

Comment: Yep!         var string = '$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("wt:static.content", "bonus10", array("DEFAULT_LANG" => array(0 => "",),"LANGUAGE_ID" => "","USE_DEFAULT" => "Y","INCLUDE_LANGUAGE" => "","CACHE_TYPE" => "Y","CACHE_TIME" => "3600"),false,array("ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y","HIDE_ICONS" => "N"));require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>';